# Is safe to allow Database accessible from internet

Tags: security

We have a database that many clients need to read/write via internet.
There are two methods to deploy:

**(A) [Database server] <---internet/SSL---> [Clients]:**  Allow database can be directly accessed from internet using SSL connection.

**(B) [Database server] <--- LAN --> [Application Server] <---internet/webAPI---> [Clients]:** Database can be locally accessed only by Application Server.
Application server provide webAPI (https) for clients to read/write to database.

is method (A) safe? Which is best pratice for this scenario (in security/performance ...)?

Answer (score -2):

Database having internet access is not good, It's increase the risk of SQL-Injection and other attack via  access point.

If wanted to add give DB access to client via internet then using VPN is good choice.